# User membership expire calculation logic

Tags: mysql

I have a "user" table and a "membership" table.

Say, today is **2012-05-09**

**user table**

```
ID   name        regDt
1    user - A    2012-03-05
```

**user_membership table**

```
userID membershipID isCurrent   startDate      endDate       dateTaken
  1      10            1        2012-03-05    2012-07-03    2012-03-05
  1      5             0        2012-07-04    2012-09-02    2012-04-28
```

**membership table**

```
ID   title     days
5    Silver    60
10   Gold      120
```

Above data denotes that a user "user -A" has taken a membership plan "Gold(120 days)" on 2012-03-05. He again took an another membership plan "Silver" (before his Gold plan expired) on 2012-04-28. 
Suppose, today is **2012-05-09.**

Now, I need a way to list all the users' whose membership plan has expired. Depending on that I will log them out from their existing sessions and send them emails with a link to take a new plan. I can scan all the data of "user" table using a cron job and currently I am doing it.

But, if there are 20,000+ users then the processing will become slow. So, can you suggest me any logic or plan so that I can limit the number of users to be scanned on each day?

Comment: Isn;t the end date already in there? `endDate`?

Comment: You want a list of users who have unexpired plans?  Or those who only have expired plans?  It's not clear.

Comment: Why not [`MySQL Scheduler`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html) ?

Comment: @putvande "endDate" is already there. But, I need to identify the users whose membership days are elapsed using a cron job. I can scan all the users but the problem is what if there are 20000+ users? That will consume a lots of system resource. Thanks.

Comment: @eggyal I have updated my question. Please read again. Thanks.

Comment: @HAL9000 Thanks for your reply. I did not know about MySql Scheduler. But I cant use MySql Scheduler becuase upon expiration I need to send the user a email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query scans for all users in the data base whose membership expires on the current date.
This query assumes you are using mysql and your date columns are in some sort of date type

```
SELECT  UM.* /* dont use *, grab whatever you feel is needed */
FROM user_membership UM
WHERE UM.endDate = CURDATE() /* OR '2012-05-09' */
```

This query will grab only the records that have an endDate equal to CURDATE(). which is just the current date. (change that to 2012-05-09 to fit your condition)

OR if you mean that specific user, then first you need his/her ID

```
SELECT UM.* /* again choose what you want from this table */
FROM user_membership UM
WHERE UM.endDate = '2012-05-09' AND UM.userID = /* THE USERS ID!!!! */
```

This query finds that user ONLY if he has a membership that expired on that certain day.

Comment: Thanks @kchang4. Your first query helped me. Thank you. Now, I have one more question regarding this. Say, I am running the cron job every day once with your suggested query. Say, my cron job fails one day. Then the "CURDATE()" will not be evaluated. What do you suggest?

Comment: you would probably have to log each execution, or it the script email you if the script fails to check.  one way or another, it has to be written down somewhere.  Adding it too the cdoe shoudlnt be hard because you can just add it in an if clause or throw an exception that specifically handls it the way you want it it to.

Comment: Thankssss. I am a dumb. I have been thinking of logging each record instead of logging each execution as you suggested. Thanks a lot.

Comment: just log the failed ones actually. so you know right away.

Comment: yeah.. I can do a try.catch block to make it fail proof. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

userID and isCurrent should both be keys, this will greatly speed up processing.

isCurrent should be set to 1 as long as the package is not expired, or hasn't been cancelled(refund chargeback, whatever). the following query can then be used:

```
Select sum(*) as isActive
FROM user_membership
where isCurrent = 1 and 
startDate >= CURDATE() and
endDate <= CURDATE() and
userID='1';
```

Check if isActive is > 0 to see if the membership is active.